# r - Calculate % within a Sub Group using Dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to chart the relative no of fatalities by year for each of various event types.

I can do with with facets in ggplot but am struggling to calculate the % By Event based on Event, Year and no of fatalities.

```
Event Type Year  Fatalities  % by Event 
                             (calculated)
-----      ----  ----------  ---------- 
Storm      1980           5  12.5%
Storm      1981           9  22.5%
Storm      1982          15  37.5%
Storm      1983          11  27.5%
Ice        1980           7  70%
Ice        1981           3  30%
```

I have the following code to calculate it, but the calculation is not working with the % using a much higher denominator.

```
fatalitiesByYearType <- stormDF %>% 
    group_by(eventType) %>% 
    mutate(totalEventFatalities = sum(FATALITIES)) %>%
    group_by(year, add = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(fatalitiesPct =  sum(FATALITIES) / totalEventFatalities)
```

What am I doing wrong?

My charting as a below.  I include this in case as I'm also interested to see whether there is a way of showing data in a proportionate way within ggplot.

```
p <- ggplot(data = fatalitiesByYearType,
    aes(x=factor(year),y=fatalitiesPct)) 
p + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    facet_wrap(.~eventType, nrow = 5) +
    labs(x = "Year", 
         y = "Fatalities",
         title = "Fatalities by Type")
```

Comment: It works on mine...unless I misunderstood you. I get the result in decimals (0.125, 0.225, 0.375, ...). Is this what you are looking for? Unless you mean that you want it to display the `%` sign, in which case you will need something like, `... %>% mutate(fatalitiesPct = paste0((100* sum(Fatalities) / totalEventFatalities), '%'))`

Comment: I think its because my DF still has all the observations in it, whereas I just want one per event/ year

Comment: This does not apply here because each observation is unique on event/year. But If that's the case then you should probably use `... %>% summarise(...)` at the end instead of mutate

Comment: Than I get Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `fatalitiesPct` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 223

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I do not get your problem, but we can start from here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# here the dplyr part
  dats <- fatalitiesByYearType %>%
          group_by(eventType) %>% 
          mutate(totalEventFatalities = sum(FATALITIES)) %>%
          group_by(year, add = TRUE) %>% 
          # here we add the summarise
          summarise(fatalitiesPct =  sum(FATALITIES) / totalEventFatalities)     
     dats
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   eventType [?]
  eventType  year fatalitiesPct
  <fct>     <int>         <dbl>
1 Ice        1980         0.7  
2 Ice        1981         0.3  
3 Storm      1980         0.125
4 Storm      1981         0.225
5 Storm      1982         0.375
6 Storm      1983         0.275
```

You can clearly merge everything in an unique `dplyr` chain:

```
# here the ggplot2 part     
    p <- ggplot(dats,aes(x=factor(year),y=fatalitiesPct)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity") +
         facet_wrap(.~eventType, nrow = 5) +
         labs(x = "Year", y = "Fatalities", title = "Fatalities by Type") +
         # here we add the % in the plot
         scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

---

With data:

```
fatalitiesByYearType <- read.table(text = "eventType year  FATALITIES  
                                   Storm      1980           5  
                                   Storm      1981           9  
                                   Storm      1982          15  
                                   Storm      1983          11  
                                   Ice        1980           7  
                                   Ice        1981           3  ",header = T)
```